# Getting intermittent AJAX.js error on a Commerce site when changing product variation dropdown menu

Tags: commerce, javascript, ajax

We've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for weeks now without luck and am really hoping someone here can help point us in the right direction.

We have a D8/Commerce 2 site with a **very intermittent ** issue. When changing the product variation dropdown on the add to cart form sometimes the variation does not update (the sku, photo, etc) remain on the default even though the dropdown is changed. When this issue occurs the console log shows the below error but we are unable to make sense of it.

Also, the fact that it is intermittent really make troubleshooting difficult.

1. JS aggregation is turned off
2. When the issue occurs it seems to occur
   until the caches are cleared and them will eventually pop up again
3. No custom caching or sever caching is being used

We've removed just about every extra service and script from the product pages but the error still persists.

Any ideas what it could be? Why it is intermittent? Or any suggestions for troubleshooting steps?

[image]

Comment: Please do not repost the same question, edit/update the previous one instead: [Intermittent AJAX error on Commerce Product pages causing pricing not to update when variations are changed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297396/intermittent-ajax-error-on-commerce-product-pages-causing-pricing-not-to-update)

Comment: Anything in Drupal's log? `/admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all in the logs relating to this issue.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? in you look in the network tab in DevTools you can find that one request returns Json and sometimes it returns a html page, if it returns a html page then you have the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.